# Preventing crosshair from moving on hover with flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have a plot drawn with [flot](https://chromium.googlesource.com/experimental/chromium/src/+/refs/wip/bajones/webvr/third_party/flot/jquery.flot.crosshair.min.js?autodive=0%2F) in javascript.

I continuously set the crosshair position so that it is in sync with an audioPlayer.

```
this.crossHairPos = newAudioPosition;
     this.setCrosshair({
       x: this.crossHairPos
     })
```

However, when I move my mouse over the plot the crosshair moves to my mouse. I think I should maybe use lockCrosshair, but I haven't succeeded yet:

```
 lockCrosshair({x: this.crossHairPos});
```

Comment: Can you create a example with [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that recreates the problem? [This JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yjkw88o8/) demonstrates setting, locking, and unlocking the crosshair without issue.

Comment: Thanks, a combination of unlockCrosshair and lockCrosshair did the trick. I was dealing with this code: http://plnkr.co/edit/PzU4yjzczBuWDGP5MaKL?p=preview

Comment: Do you want to post this as an answer @mechenbier ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yjkw88o8/) demonstrates setting, locking, and unlocking the crosshair without issue.

You'll want to use both the `lockCrosshair` and `unlockCrosshair` function:

```
$('#lock-crosshair').on('click', function() {
  plot.lockCrosshair({
    x: 4
  });
});

$('#unlock-crosshair').on('click', function() {
  plot.unlockCrosshair();
});
```